# change this this TopKFrequentElements code to handle cases of duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary, data-structures

```
class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: list[int], k: int) -> list[int]:
        count = {}
        freq = [[] for i in range(len(nums) + 1)]

        for n in nums:
            count[n] = 1 + count.get(n, 0)
        for n, c in count.items():
            freq[c].append(n)

        res = []
        for i in range(len(freq) - 1, 0, -1):
            for n in freq[i]:
                res.append(n)
                if len(res) == k:
                    return res
                
sol = Solution()
nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
k = 2
print(sol.topKFrequent(nums, k))
```

The output here is: [1,2]

It should be: [1, [2, 3]]
, because there are as many 2's as there are 3's.

If there aren't any duplicate cases, the output should be as usual, a list of k elements where all elements are a single digit.

I tried a lot of ways like adding a counter variable and another list for the duplicates to eventually append to the result list, failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
...

for n, c in count.items():
    freq[c].append(n)
```

With the example you provided (`nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]`), once that loop is finished this is what `freq` contains:

```
[[], [4], [2, 3], [1], [], [], [], [], []]
```

which means, from left to right:

- There are no elements (empty list) that appears zero times.
- There is one element, which is the number 4, that appears once.
- There are two elements, which are the number 2 and 3, that appear twice.
- There is one element, which is the number 1, that appears three times.
- There are no elements (empty list) that appears four times.
- ...

So what you basically have to do is to return the `k` elements of `freq` with the biggest indexes that are not an empty list. (with `k=2`, it would be `[[1, [2, 3]]`).

---

### First solution (improvable)

This is the solution following your approach of considering `freq` as a list of lists. This isn't memory efficient as you are creating more lists than the ones you need:

```
def topKFrequent(self, nums: list[int], k: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    count = {}
    for n in nums:
        count[n] = 1 + count.get(n, 0)

    freq = [[] for i in range(len(nums) + 1)]
    for n, c in count.items():
        freq[c].append(n)
    # print(freq)     # [[], [4], [2, 3], [1], [], [], [], [], []]

    freq = [f for f in freq if f]
    # print(freq)     # [[4], [2, 3], [1]]

    freq.reverse()
    # print(freq)     # [[1], [2, 3], [4]]

    return freq[:k]   # [[1], [2, 3]]
```

In the code above I have:

1. Removed the empty lists from `freq`
2. Reversed `freq`
3. Returned the first `k` elements of freq

---

### Second solution (better)

Define `freq` as a dictionary where the keys are the number of repetitions and its values a list containing all the numbers that appeared key-times.

So once again with your example `nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]`:

- freq[1] = [4] -> the numbers that appear once is the number 4.
- freq[2] = [2, 3] -> the numbers that appear twice are the numbers 2 and 3.
- freq[3] = [1] -> the numbers that appear three times is the number 1.

And then you just need to return the values of the `k` elements of `freq` with highest key number.

Possible implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def topKFrequent(self, nums: list[int], k: int) -> list[list[int]]:

    count = defaultdict(int)
    for n in nums:
        count[n] += 1
    
    freq = defaultdict(list)
    for num, count in count.items():
        freq[count] += [num]
    # print(freq)         # {3: [1], 2: [2, 3], 1: [4]}

    freq_items = list(freq.items())
    # print(freq_items)   # [(3, [1]), (2, [2, 3]), (1, [4])]

    sorted_items = sorted(freq_items, reverse=True)
    # print(sorted_items) # [(3, [1]), (2, [2, 3]), (1, [4])]
    # ^^^it doesn't change due to the example, but it is needed^^^

    return [item[1] for item in sorted_items[:k]]   # [[1], [2, 3]]
```